# how to select entire row in bootstrap date picker within the month

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I want to select the entire row within the month.

let me explain my task.

for example:august 2017 start in Tuesday , I want to show the date of Tuesday to Saturday in the text box.

If the user select 28 th of august 2017 means I want to show the date only Sunday to Thursday in the text box. similarly  I want to get the result by every month.

Here I have created fiddle 
[Click here to see the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vinothsm92/9usq3enn/395/)

```
   var firstDate = moment(value, "DD-MM-YYYY").day(0).format("DD-MM-YYYY");
      var lastDate =  moment(value, "DD-MM-YYYY").day(6).format("DD-MM-YYYY");
```

I don't know how to do this.  can anyone tell me is this possible to achieve this and give some tips to achieve this.

Thanks

vinoth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this code**

compare `first date of row` with `month first date` && `last date of row` with `month last date`.

```
  $('#weeklyDatePicker').on('dp.change', function (e) {
      var _year=e.date.year(),
      _month=e.date.month(),
      _date=e.date.date(),
      _day=e.date.day(),
      monthFirstDate = new Date(_year, _month, 1),
      monthLastDate = new Date(_year, _month + 1, 0),
      firstDate = new Date(_year, _month, _date - _day),
      lastDate = new Date(_year, _month, _date - _day + 6),
      fromDate=(firstDate<=monthFirstDate)?monthFirstDate:firstDate,
      toDate=(lastDate>=monthLastDate)?monthLastDate:lastDate,
      fromDateFormated=moment(fromDate).format("DD-MM-YYYY"),
      toDateFormated=moment(toDate).format("DD-MM-YYYY");
      $("#weeklyDatePicker").val(fromDateFormated);
      $("#weeklyDatePickerend").val(toDateFormated);
  });
```

```js
  
$(document).ready(function(){


  $("#weeklyDatePicker").datetimepicker({
      format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
  });
  $('#weeklyDatePicker').on('dp.change', function (e) {
      var _year=e.date.year(),
      _month=e.date.month(),
      _date=e.date.date(),
      _day=e.date.day(),
      monthFirstDate = new Date(_year, _month, 1),
      monthLastDate = new Date(_year, _month + 1, 0),
      firstDate = new Date(_year, _month, _date - _day),
      lastDate = new Date(_year, _month, _date - _day + 6),
      fromDate=(firstDate<=monthFirstDate)?monthFirstDate:firstDate,
      toDate=(lastDate>=monthLastDate)?monthLastDate:lastDate,
      fromDateFormated=moment(fromDate).format("DD-MM-YYYY"),
      toDateFormated=moment(toDate).format("DD-MM-YYYY");
      $("#weeklyDatePicker").val(fromDateFormated);
      $("#weeklyDatePickerend").val(toDateFormated);
  });
});
```

```css
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget tr:hover {
    background-color: #0d75b3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
            <div class="input-group" id="DateDemo">
              From Date:<input type='text' id='weeklyDatePicker' placeholder="Select Week" />
              <br>
                   To Date:<input type='text' id='weeklyDatePickerend' placeholder="Select Week" />
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```